# When do linearly independent vectors together with their sum-vector form an affinely independent set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x_1,\dots,x_k\subset \mathbb R^n$ be linearly independent vectors and let $x_{k+1}=\sum_{j=1}^k x_j$ be their vector sum.

When are the vectors $x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1}$ affinely independent?

This is for example true for $n=2,k=2$ with the vectors $(1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$, which are linearly dependent, but affinely independent.

Comment: What does "affinely dependent" mean?  This is not a term commonly used in linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to the question on [Affine Independence and Linear Independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82189/affine-independence-and-linear-independence)  the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are called affinely independent if there do not exist real numbers $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ that are not all zero such that $\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i v_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i = 0$.

Suppose that the vectors $x_1,\dots,x_{k+1}$ are affinely dependent. Then there exist real numbers $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{k+1}$ that are not all zero such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \alpha_i x_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \alpha_i = 0$.  Since the vectors $x_1,\dots,x_k$ are linearly independent, $\alpha_{k+1}\not=0=-\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j$. From the other side, after the rearrangement we obtain $\sum_{i=1}^k (\alpha_i-\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j) x_i=0$. Hence we have $\alpha_i=\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j$ for each $i$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j=k\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i$. Therefore $k=1$.